# In Jenkins permission issues while running an Ansible playbook

Tags: jenkins, ansible, jenkins-plugins, devops

Permission issues in Jenkins while running an Ansible playbook.
console Log:
[Console Log says permission denied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UwB7e.png) 
when i run the same in from putty directly is runs:
Putty Log:[Putty executes successfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3oH7k.png)

Comment: Are you using the same user when running in Jenkins as you do via Putty ?

Comment: If you run it from jenkins, the ssh key for the jenkins user (probably in `~jenkins/.ssh/.id_rsa`) must be allowed by the guest you are trying to deploy to. When you run it locally (I assume you are doing that when you refer to `putty`) it will use your ssh key. So add the public key from the jenkins user to the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file on the guest

Comment: you should modify the `ansible-playbook` command with -u root and pass the private key as well with `--key-file=`

Answer (score 0):

SSH into your remote server and do a `sudo cat /var/log/secure|grep sshd` to get and insight of what's going on.

Assuming it is a permissions issue, be sure that your remote jenkin's user `~/.ssh` folder and the files inside of it (usually there is a *authorized_keys* file there) have full ownership and the right permissions.

Jenkins remote user should be the owner and part of the group that owns the directory:

`sudo chown -R jenkins.jenkins_group ~/.ssh`

Set the permissions on the SSH directory:

`sudo chmod 700 ~/.shh`

And set the permissions to your SSH keys file:

`sudo chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`